# How to replace a specific view in iCarousel on tap/select?

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, icarousel

I'm using iCarousel by @Nick Lookwood to load a scrollable list of "flashcards".

Each View of the iCarousel control is one flashcard. By design, I require that when a user taps the flashcard (view), the flashcard flips to reveal the behind. Before using iCarousel, I was making two separate controls, one for front and one for back, and then using UIView.Transition (with a nice Flip From Top animation) to go from front to back when a Tap was detected, or the other way round.

Adding a UITapGestureRecognizer to my View is leading to weird artifacts and not functioning as expected (overlapping controls, the next one instead of the current one flipping, no animation, etc.) and I need a different approach. I could conveniently use the Selected event in the iCarousel Delegate instead of a Tap Gesture Recognizer, but what do I do there exactly?

In essence, I would like to replace the specific view **which** was tapped with another but I feel this is conflicting with the whole reusable views idea. Is there nothing I can do? (Once the view is out of the screen, I am fine with it being "flipped forward" again.)

Thanks!

p

P.S. I'm using C# and Xamarin.iOS, but I can understand Obj-C and Swift code fairly well, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: for what its worth, iCarousel doesn't really care whether you reuse the supplied view or not.  Can't you just trigger the animation on your view when the view is selected?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of example for iCarausal. I assume you are using this :

[iCarausal](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)

and specifically folder name "**Basic iOS Example**"

How about the below changes in delegate methods:

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *label = nil;

    //create new view if no view is available for recycling
    if (view == nil)
    {
        //don't do anything specific to the index within
        //this `if (view == nil) {...}` statement because the view will be
        //recycled and used with other index values later
        view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0f, 200.0f)];
        ((UIImageView *)view).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"page.png"];
        view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

        //back view i have just added this apart from it there is no change made by me in this method
        UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds];
        backView.tag = 2;
        [backView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [view addSubview:backView];
        [backView setHidden:YES];
        //back view

        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        label.font = [label.font fontWithSize:50];
        label.tag = 1;
        [view addSubview:label];



    }
    else
    {
        //get a reference to the label in the recycled view
        label = (UILabel *)[view viewWithTag:1];
    }

    //set item label
    //remember to always set any properties of your carousel item
    //views outside of the `if (view == nil) {...}` check otherwise
    //you'll get weird issues with carousel item content appearing
    //in the wrong place in the carousel
    label.text = [_items[index] stringValue];

    return view;
}
```

and implementing didSelect delegate as below:

```
- (void)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index{

    UIView *frontview = [carousel itemViewAtIndex:index];
    UIView *backView = [frontview viewWithTag:2];

    BOOL isInFront = NO;

    if (backView.hidden == NO) {
        isInFront = YES;
    }
    [UIView transitionWithView: isInFront ? backView : frontview
                      duration:1.0
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                    animations:^{
                        [backView setHidden:isInFront];
                    }
                    completion:nil];

}
```

You should write your code more structured, it was an example to show you that you can acheive what you want with iCarausal.